# Returned result does not display on HTML page

Tags: javascript

Generates 26 buttons that have the value of every letter in the alphabet.
Then it adds an event listener to every button that should fetch results based on that button value and then displays them using displayMealCards.
Anywhere I add console.log(), I get results after I click an "alphabet Button" but they don't show up on my HTML page.

```js
let alphabetContainer = document.querySelector(".alphabet-container");

// Alphabet Button HTML
function getAlphabetButtonHtml(letter) {
  let alphabetButton = `<button class="letter-btn" value="${letter}">${letter}</button>`;
  return alphabetButton;
}

// Add HTML Button to every letter in the alphabet
function getAlphabetButtonsHtml() {
  let alphabetButtons = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    letter = String.fromCharCode(i + 65);
    alphabetButtons.push(getAlphabetButtonHtml(letter));
  }
  return alphabetButtons;
}

function displayAlphabetButtons() {
  alphabetContainer.innerHTML = `
    <h2 class="section-title">Find recipes that start with:</h2>
    <div class="alphabet-buttons">
      ${getAlphabetButtonsHtml().join("")}
    </div>`;
}

displayAlphabetButtons();

// DISPLAY ALPHABET RESULTS
const letterButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".letter-btn");

// letterButtons is a HTML Collection. Add eventListener with forEach
letterButtons.forEach((letter) => {
  letter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //call getRecipeCards to fetch the results and display them
    getRecipeCards(letter.value).then(displayMealCards);
  });
});

async function getRecipeCards(letter) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=${letter}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

function displayMealCards(meals) {
  let mealCardsContainer = document.querySelector(
    ".meal-card-results-container"
  );

  mealCardsContainer.innerHTML = `
  <div class="meal-card-results">
    ${meals.meals.map((meal) => {
      getMealCardHtml(meal);
    })}
    </div>`;
  return mealCardsContainer;
}

function getMealCardHtml(meal) {
  let mealCard = `
  <div class="meal-card">
    <a href="#"><h3 class="meal-card-title">${meal.strMeal}</h3></a>
  </div>`;
  return mealCard;
}
```

```html
      <div class="container alphabet-container"></div>
      <div class="container meal-card-results-container">
       
      </div>
```

Comment: Typo: `${meals.meals.map((meal) => {
      getMealCardHtml(meal);
    })}` Your map callback doesn't `return` anything

Answer (score 0):

Since you call `getMealCardHtml(meal);` from a function, you need return it's result:

```js
let alphabetContainer = document.querySelector(".alphabet-container");

// Alphabet Button HTML
function getAlphabeButtonHtml(letter) {
  let alphabetButton = `<button class="letter-btn" value="${letter}">${letter}</button>`;
  return alphabetButton;
}

// Add HTML Button to every letter in the alphabet
function getAlphabetButtonsHtml() {
  let alphabetButtons = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    letter = String.fromCharCode(i + 65);
    alphabetButtons.push(getAlphabeButtonHtml(letter));
  }
  return alphabetButtons;
}

function displayAlphabetButtons() {
  alphabetContainer.innerHTML = `
    <h2 class="section-title">Find recipes that start with:</h2>
    <div class="alphabet-buttons">
      ${getAlphabetButtonsHtml().join("")}
    </div>`;
}

displayAlphabetButtons();

// DISPLAY ALPHABET RESULTS
const letterButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".letter-btn");

// letterButtons is a HTML Collection. Add eventListener with forEach
letterButtons.forEach((letter) => {
  letter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //call getRecipeCards to fetch the results and display them
    getRecipeCards(letter.value).then(displayMealCards);
  });
});

async function getRecipeCards(letter) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=${letter}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

function displayMealCards(meals) {
  let mealCardsContainer = document.querySelector(
    ".meal-card-results-container"
  );

  mealCardsContainer.innerHTML = `
  <div class="meal-card-results">
    ${meals.meals.map((meal) => {
      return getMealCardHtml(meal);
    })}
    </div>`;
  return mealCardsContainer;
}

function getMealCardHtml(meal) {
  let mealCard = `
  <div class="meal-card">
    <a href="#"
      ><img
        src="./uuuspp1468263334.jpg"
        alt="food"
        class="meal-card-img"
    /></a>
    <a href="#"><h3 class="meal-card-title">${meal.strMeal}</h3></a>
    <div class="meal-card-meta">
      <a href="#" class="meal-card-tag">Chicken</a>
      <a href="#" class="meal-card-flag-link"
        ><img
          src="./flags/Mexican.png"
          alt="Mexican"
          class="flag-img meal-card-flag-img"
      /></a>
    </div>
    <p class="meal-card-intro">
      Put your wine, shallot, herbs and peppercorns into a small pot and
      bring to the boil, then simmer slowly for...
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="meal-card-button">Read More</a>
  </div>`;
  return mealCard;
}
```

```html
<div class="container alphabet-container"></div>
      <div class="container meal-card-results-container">
       
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the innermost braces from
`meals.meals.map((meal) => { getMealCardHtml(meal); })` or add `return` after the opening brace, the map will result in something to work with. In other words, the current lambda for `meals.meals.map` does not return anything.

Aside: you can use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to avoid adding 26 handler functions. A [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
const alphabetContainer = document.querySelector(`.alphabet-container`);

for (let i = 65; i < 91; i += 1) {
  alphabetContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(
    `beforeend`,
    `${i%13 == 0 ? `<br>` : ``}<button data-letter="${String.fromCharCode(i)}">${
      String.fromCharCode(i)}</button>`
  );
}

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.letter) {
    return getRecipeCards(evt.target.dataset.letter);
  }
}

async function getRecipeCards(letter) {
  const response = await 
    fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=${letter}`)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => writeResult(r, letter));
}

function writeResult(recipes, letter) {
  const resultContainer = document.querySelector(`.meal-card-results-container`);
  resultContainer.textContent = ``;
  resultContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(
      `beforeend`,
      `<h3>Meals (${letter})</h3>`);
  recipes.meals.forEach( meal => 
    resultContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(
      `beforeend`,
      `<div>${meal.strMeal}</div>`) 
  );
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2rem;
} 

button {
  margin: 2px 2px 0;
  font-family: 'courier new';
}
```

```html
<div class="container alphabet-container"></div>
<div class="container meal-card-results-container"></div>
```